# How to install PyTorch on ppc64le with pip?

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, powerpc

I am going to build a virtual environment (python -m venv) and install PyTorch on a ppc64le machine. But there is no package in pip to install PyTorch, however it is available in conda. But I wanted not to use conda because I need to install some specific packages and versions. So, how can I install PyTorch on a ppc64le(IBM Power8) machine?